# Hide Discount from line Items in Quotes in SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

Want to hide the discount field from the line Items in Quote module.

How to do that?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to edit the "quotes.js" file located in the quotes module and remove the generated element from the add row method.

This can be done in an upgrade safe way by creating a copy of the quotes.js file in the custom directory. You will also need to specify a custom view.edit and EditViewFooter.html and change the references in each of the files to point to the custom directory.

Here are a list of files that you need to create/modify...

```
custom/modules/Quotes/metadata/editviewdefs.php
custom/modules/Quotes/quotes.js
custom/modules/Quotes/tpls/EditViewFooter.tpl
custom/modules/Quotes/views/view.edit.php
```